# Using BETWEEN or comparison operators in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm having trouble with using the between operator in where clause. I have the following queries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE timestamp_column BETWEEN (current_date - interval '1 day')::date 
                           AND current_date   => 500k rows
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE timestamp_column >= (current_date - interval '1 day')::date => 1 mil rows
```

Does anyone have any idea why the result set is different? Shouldn't it be the same? I am trying to compare the number of rows from a database in PostgreSQL with data from Sybase ASE. The same 2 queries ran in Sybase give the same results. The expected result set is 1 milion rows. This should be the number of rows that I have between yesterday and today.

PostgreSQL v9.5, timestamp_column = timestamp without time zone

I tried using now(), current_timestamp but same result.

What am I missing here? If I didn't made myself clear let me know.

Comment: Well, the queries do something different. It's not a surprise that they return different results (specifically: the first query will not include rows where `timestamp_column` is bigger then today)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm trying to understand why the result set is different. I want to retrieve the results from T - 1 to T. If writing >= T -1 isn't like writing between T- 1 and T?

Comment: The first one is equivalent to `timstamp_column >= current_date - 1 and timestamp_column <= current_date` obviously that is something different then just `timstamp_column >= current_date - 1`

Comment: There is a misconception: there is not a single time instant *between yesterday and today* -- Your first query returns rows, where `timestamp_column` is between yesterday **midnight** (00:00) and today **midnight** (00:00). It obviously misses any rows, which is truly *today* (i.e. after today midnight). The second includes them, with possibly any future rows too.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes you are right. I wasn't seeing clearly enoguh. Running this in Sybase fooled me because the behaviour is not the same between these two. I mean, in Sybase you get more results, including T day.

Comment: @pozs Thanks for the explanation. As I said i was misguided by the fact that Sybase returned different result set using the same type of query.

Comment: @MisterM: if Sybase really returns the same number of rows for both statements, then you either have different data in Sybase then you have in Postgres or Sybase is seriously broken (or there is some timstamp/date conversion going on that isn't obvious). From a pure SQL point of view - and if there **are** rows "after today"  - those two can not return the same results

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The conversion in Sybase seems to be different, it returns the data that includes 'today'. Only after a conversion of 'today' it returns what it should return.